# How to get the name of a request via Nock object

Tags: nock

At the point in my test code where I check assert that all nocks have been called, I have a semi-useful error message to dumps out if a nock wasn't called (since the default error message is useless):

```
try {
  assertions(data, result);
  if (assertNock !== null) {
    // Expect that all mocked calls were made
    if (nock.isDone() !== !!assertNock) {
      console.error('One or more of your Nock matchers was never called.');
    }
    expect(nock.isDone()).toBe(!!assertNock);
  }
  done();
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to specify *which* call wasn't made. But, I can't seem to find a way to get that information from the `nock` object, which looks like:

```
{ [Function: startScope]
  emitter:
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined },
  define: [Function: define],
  loadDefs: [Function: loadDefs],
  load: [Function: load],
  enableNetConnect: [Function: enableNetConnect],
  disableNetConnect: [Function: disableNetConnect],
  removeInterceptor: [Function: removeInterceptor],
  activeMocks: [Function: activeMocks],
  pendingMocks: [Function: pendingMocks],
  isDone: [Function: isDone],
  isActive: [Function: isActive],
  activate: [Function: activate],
  cleanAll: [Function: cleanAll],
  recorder:
   { rec: [Function: record],
     clear: [Function: clear],
     play: [Function] },
  back: { [Function: Back] setMode: [Function], fixtures: null, currentMode: 'dryrun' },
  restore: [Function: restore]
}
```

How can I get useful/identifying information about the request that was't made from the nock object?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock#read-this---about-interceptors), interceptors are removed once they have been called. With that knowledge, one can then use `nock.activeMocks()` which will return an array of items that are still active. If you have added `.persist()` to any of the nocks they will still be in the list. In that case you may want to use `nock.pendingMocks()` which will only return the nocks that haven't yet been called.

```
    nock.activeMocks(); // [ 'GET https://www.example.com:443/fake/url', 'POST https://sts.amazonaws.com:443/' ]
    nock.pendingMocks(); // [ 'GET https://www.example.com:443/fake/url' ]
```